# function "cancel" adds edited form instead cancel it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm working on functions for form. Data for this form comes from api call and filling input fields. Submit button works well, but behavior of cancel button is weird, instead of cancel last changes it sends updated data to db. Could anybody help me to find my mistake? 
Also I have tried to `type="reset"` and it returns default empty fields but I need that it has returned old value before editing

My form:

```
<form style="padding: 15px" ng-submit="submitForm()">
       <div class="form-group row">
            <div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!id' | filter: '!0' " ng-model="rowValue">
                <label for="rowValue"  class="col-sm-2">
                       {{k | hide:'.name' | makeUppercase}}:
               </label>
            <div class=" col-sm-2" >
                <input class="form-control rowValue"  id="rowValue" ng-model="rowData[k]" ng-disabled="isDisabled()"/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData" >Save</button>
 <button  type="button" class="btn" ng-if="rowData" ng-click="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
```

js

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {

        $scope.$watch('rowData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldValue, 'newValue:', newValue);
            }, true);

        $http({
            method  : 'PUT',
            url     : $scope.globalUrl + $scope.id,
            data    : $scope.rowData //form
        })
        .then(function (res) {
                return res;
            })
            .then(function (){
                $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                    'url': $scope.globalUrl
                });
            })
    };

        $scope.cancelForm = function () {
            $scope.$watch('rowData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                return oldValue;
                console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldValue, 'newValue:', newValue);
            }, true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-if="rowData" ng-click="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
```

To

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" ng-if="rowData" ng-click="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
```

When you put `type="submit"` this means that on click it will do the submit action on your form

Comment: my fault I did wrong post, this is how is currently in my app, but the problem is still opened